# How to share products from multiple stores in front end?

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Is it possible to share products from multiple stores in front end?

I have:
Store A with url: www..com/A with products A1, A2 
Store B with url: www..com/B with products B1, B2

And my goal is to have www..com with products A1, A2, B1, B2. Is it possible?

I cannot have a store with all products because i want employees from each stores to manage only there own products only. So the employee EA from store A cannot see products from store B.

I want to have this because my website has products from several stores but my front end must look like from one store only. But in the same time, I want to manage in BO the stores individually. How do you propose to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/296563-how-to-share-produts-from-multiple-stores-in-front-end/.

The solution is to purchase the module:
http://addons-modules.com/store/en/multiple-sellervendor/21-agile-prestashop-multiple-seller-vendor-module.html

Answer (score 0):

no it is not 
check this it is prestashop DOC
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/The+multistore+interface